# Should a controller wrap a collection into a Flux?

Tags: spring-webflux

Whenever I have a collection of object I need to return in a spring webflux controller, should I return a normal collection or a flux?

Now I use normal collections:

```
@GetMapping("/)
fun getData(): List<DomainObject> {
  return inmemorycache.getAll()
}
```

Just wondering if it works different if I wrap into flux. The code has no async boundaries inside, everything is already in memory.
Could you possibly point me to some docs clarifying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever I have a collection of object I need to return in a spring webflux controller, should I return a normal collection or a flux?

Your stated options here are a bit odd. If you're not using a reactive stack, then your only sensible option is a standard collection. You wouldn't wrap it into a reactive type, that would make zero sense and only serve to confuse.

If you're using Webflux however, implying a reactive stack, then your choices are presumably returning either a `Mono<List<DomainObject>>` or a `Flux<DomainObject>`. (You can't return a standard collection, or else you'd have to block.)

The short answer is that in most scenarios, you almost certainly want a `Mono<List<DomainObject>>` rather than a `Flux<DomainObject>`.

A `Flux` is a stream of 0 to n values, which may or may not ever finish, and may have an arbitrary time between each element. It's normally delivered to the client in a ["newline delimited JSON"](http://ndjson.org/) format or similar, via a connection that's held open and pipes data as and when it's available. Typical applications might include subscribing to a message queue, delivering instant messages to a browser via a websocket (for example.)

If on the other hand you have a standard list of values that you want to return to the client in one go - there a `Mono<List<DomainObject>` makes much more sense. It's a value delivered in one go (hence `Mono`), and would normally be delivered as part of a standard request / response model, where the response would be a standard JSON object containing said list (and whatever other attributes you wanted to add of course.) This is the "normal" approach, and if you're using a flux upstream as part of that processing, there's nothing wrong with calling `collectList()` on it to transform it to a `Mono`.